ld merge all `*.str1.4` strings
I crosscompile for cortex M microcontroller using arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi
I compile using -fdata-sections and link using -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--sort-section=alignment
In map file I found something I cannot understand:
[...]
 *(SORT_BY_ALIGNMENT(.rodata*str1.4))
 .rodata.saiPrintHeader.str1.4
                0x3004a558    0x192e1 build/src/main_task.c.o
                                 0x58 (size before relaxing)
 .rodata.saiPrintData.str1.4
                0x30063839       0x1f build/src/main_task.c.o
 .rodata.main_Task.str1.4
                0x30063839      0x143 build/src/main_task.c.o
 .rodata.main_Task_Init.str1.4
                0x30063839       0x36 build/src/main_task.c.o
 .rodata.__qassert_fail.str1.4
                0x30063839       0x21 build/src/qassert.c.o
 .rodata.sampleCollector_FindByName.str1.4
                0x30063839       0x25 build/src/sampleCollector.c.o
[...]

I don't understand why .rodata.saiPrintHeader.str1.4 is so big after the relaxing, and I don't understand why the other symbols are all at the same address.
with a hex editor I saw that at address 0x3004a558 there are all the strings, so it's like the linker merges all the strings together.
What is the benefit of doing such a thing? Is it possible to make it so that in the elf each string has its own address?
